# ProgressBar not updating correctly after return to Activity

Tags: android, android-progressbar

`MyBookshelf` extends `Activity` and implements an Interface called by asynchronous download and unzip processes.

The asynchronous download process periodically calls `onBookDownloadPercent(float)` from the Interface.  My Activity definition includes:

```
public class MyBookshelf extends Activity implements BookDownloadListener {

    private ProgressBar mProgress;

    // .......
    // .......

    @Override
    public void onBookDownloadPercent(float _percent_finished) {
        final float final_percent  = _percent_finished;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run()
            {
                DebugLog.d(TAG, "onBookDownloadPercent " + Float.toString(final_percent));
                mProgress.setProgress((int) final_percent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In LogCat, my function `DebugLog.d` assures me that the UI thread is calling `mProgress.setProgress()`:

```
09-30 11:37:06.698: DEBUG/MyBookshelf(2069): onBookDownloadPercent 0.0014221431; thread 1
09-30 11:37:07.288: DEBUG/MyBookshelf(2069): onBookDownloadPercent 1.0004596; thread 1
09-30 11:37:07.838: DEBUG/MyBookshelf(2069): onBookDownloadPercent 2.0001705; thread 1
09-30 11:37:08.318: DEBUG/MyBookshelf(2069): onBookDownloadPercent 3.0014038; thread 1
09-30 11:37:09.098: DEBUG/MyBookshelf(2069): onBookDownloadPercent 4.0002813; thread 1
09-30 11:37:09.468: DEBUG/MyBookshelf(2069): onBookDownloadPercent 5.0003366; thread 1
09-30 11:37:09.818: DEBUG/MyBookshelf(2069): onBookDownloadPercent 6.0003924; thread 1
09-30 11:37:10.158: DEBUG/MyBookshelf(2069): onBookDownloadPercent 7.0004926; thread 1
09-30 11:37:10.588: DEBUG/MyBookshelf(2069): onBookDownloadPercent 8.000748; thread 1
09-30 11:37:10.938: DEBUG/MyBookshelf(2069): onBookDownloadPercent 9.000215; thread 1
09-30 11:37:11.368: DEBUG/MyBookshelf(2069): onBookDownloadPercent 10.00017; thread 1
```

I have a similar Interface for the asynchronous unzip task:

```
@Override
public void onBookUnzipPercent(float _percent_finished) {
    final float final_percent  = _percent_finished;
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run()
        {
            DebugLog.d(TAG, "onBookUnzipPercent " + Float.toString(final_percent));
            mProgress.setProgress((int) final_percent);
        }
    });
}
```

First, `MyBookshelf` calls the asynchronous task which downloads the first book, and the progress bar updates correctly (0 to 100%).

Second, `MyBookshelf` calls the asynchronous task which unzips the first book, and the progress bar updates correctly (0 to 100%).

Third, `MyBookshelf` calls `startActivity(nextIntent)` to read the book and calls `finish()` on itself.

Fourth, I come back to MyBookshelf after reading the book:

```
nextIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyBookshelf.class);
```

The Problem occurs when I download the next book: the download occurs, and LogCat logs the updates, but the progress bar is only visible as blank gray and does *not* update when downloading nor when unzipping the next book.  I have confirmed with LogCat that thread 1 is indeed running via the `onBookDownloadPerecent Runnable`

Do I need to do something interesting to `mProgress` when coming back to `MyBookshelf` so it will display when it's updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to make mProgressBar static:

```
public class MyBookshelf extends Activity implements BookDownloadListener {

    static private ProgressBar mProgress;

    // .......
    // .......

    @Override
    public void onBookDownloadPercent(float _percent_finished) {
        final float final_percent  = _percent_finished;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run()
            {
                DebugLog.d(TAG, "onBookDownloadPercent " + Float.toString(final_percent));
                mProgress.setProgress((int) final_percent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WHy dont you use the finish() when going back to the myBookShelf after reading the book?

It seems everything is ok, but I have a little doubt about this line of code

`nextIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyBookshelf.class);`

Comment: I finish() the other Activity when going back to MyBookshelf; I just didn't include that above.

Comment: It's because MyBookshelf finishes itself when calling the BookReader class.   BookReader needs to start MyBookshelf activity again.

Comment: you don't have to finish MyBookShelf in order to start BookReader. You can use StartActivityForResult to fire up the BookReader class. Once BookReader class is finished, MyBookShelf will receive a call from onActivityResult. So you dont have to init all the UI stuff again. I wonder if it's the part goes wrong. let me know :)

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion, though we did it this way for memory management reasons.  The books we're displaying are quite large and smaller devices were crashing when some bitmaps were being opened.  So to save all the memory possible, we finish unneeded processes.